# ERROR: Can't set up Node.js core modules, when creating Node.js Express app on Webstorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am getting the following error when I try to create a Node.js Express app in Webstorm:

> Can't set up Node.js v0.12.2 Core Modules Failed to create
>   C:\Users\Christina.WebStorm10\system\extLibs\nodejs-v0.12.2-src\core-modules-sources\lib\constants.js.
>   See idea.log for details (on the main menu "Help | Show Log in ...")

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that access to this file is denied.

1. **Remove nodejs-v0.xx.x-src** folder, its default location is: 
   C:\Users\.IntelliJIdea14\system\extLibs
2. In the settings dialog select **Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM**
3. Click on **Configure** button
4. In the new dialog accept defaults which is **Download from the Internet**.
5. Click on **Configure** button

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem whenever I tried to download the modules Although I didnt find the reason for this I found a solution. Try to download Node.js from their website and use the Get Modules from Directory Option in the cofig window.

Then point the path to c:/Programs and Files(x86)/Node/npm  and you should be good to go ;)